# How to make a dictionary from a list and a list of keyvalue pairs

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a list of `KeyValuePair`, of int and a custom object, Function. I also have a list of function Ids. Both lists are sorted alphabetically. I need to match up the function Ids from the 1 list to the function Ids from the other list. So, say the list of KVP looks like:

```
1, (Function.name = foo, function.Id = 4)
2, (Function.name = bar, function.Id = 7)
```

And the list of just Ids is:

```
142
154
```

I need a dictionary of:

```
{4, 142}
{7, 154}
```

So a mash up of the function Ids from both lists.

How can I do this?

Here is what I've tried:

```
    Dictionary<int, int> map = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    List<KeyValuePair<int, Function>> sorted = SortFunctions();

    IEnumerator sortEnum = sorted.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator dicEnum = FunctionIds.GetEnumerator();
    while ((sortEnum.MoveNext()) && (dicEnum.MoveNext()))
    {
        //Not sure what to do next? Just map[sortEnum.Next()] = dicEnum.Next()?
    }


    //Also was trying to use zip.. many many errors 
    List<string> sortedFuncs = sorted.ToList();
    Dictionary<int, int> map2 = functionIds.ToDictionary(x => x, x => sortedFuncs.Value.Id[functionIds.IndexOf(x)]);
```

Comment: Why does `{"Foo", 4}` match up with `142`?

Comment: The relationship between the two collections isn't entirely clear. Is the logic simply to link by index, so the KVP in the 3rd position in `sorted` matches the FunctionID in the 3rd position in `FunctionIDs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to chain `Zip` with `ToDictionary`:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, Function>> sorted = SortFunctions();

Dictionary<int, int> map2 =
    sorted.Zip(FunctionIds, (s, i) => new {key = s.Value.Id, value = i})
          .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);
```

**Explanation:**

`Zip` enumerates through the two lists and creates an anonymous type consisting of the `Id` from the `Value` of the `KeyValuePair` in `sorted` and the integer from `FunctionIds`.  Those values are stored in the `key` and `value` property of the anonymous type.

`ToDictionary` then enumerates that collection and creates a dictionary using the `key` and the `value` from the anonymous type (`x`).

Comment: Could you do that again with my variables? I'

Comment: Could you do that again with my variables? I'm confused as to what goes where.. so using my FunctionIds and sortedFuncs. Thanks!

Comment: @jcam77 I thought `sorted` and `FunctionIds` _were_ your variables.

Comment: Oh my that is a bit embarrassing.. I missed the first sorted and thought it was using FunctionIds and x. Thanks very much for the solution. I understand the first part ( (s, i) => new {key = s.Value.Id, value = i}), at least I think I do (s is the current instance from sorted and i is the current instance from FunctionIds. I'm a bit confused on the last line. Do you set the zipped sorted to a dictionary, where x.key and x.value have what value? Where do you assign what x is I guess? I'm unfamiliar with the syntax.

Comment: `x` is the anonymous type that is the output of `Zip`.  I've added a bit more explanation.